# Вопрос по синхронизации нескольких открытых вкладок с сайтом

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, дизайн, веб-дизайн

Что следует делать при переходе пользователем на соседнюю ранее открытую вкладку с сайтом, информация на которой может быть уже устарелой (например отсутствие введённых данных, каких либо настроек, предыдущий язык и тд.):

1. Перезагружать страницу прямо перед носом пользователя (отлавливая событие активации вкладки `window.onfocus`).
2. Показывать пользователю заглушку "Обновите страницу".
3. Ничего не делать.

Comment: 4. Подгрузить новые данные в фоне через ajax :)

Comment: Хотя лично я склоняюсь к пункту 3: я вполне могу оставлять открытыми вкладки как раз чтобы там остались старые данные

Answer (score 2):

Если важно сохранять актуальность одной сущности или нескольких но связанных (например если у вас одна таблица и несколько человек ее могут редактировать) - то 2 вариант.

3 вариант - если пользователь сам меняет данные и помнит об этом.

1 вариант - вообще такое делать не стоит никогда.

Comment: А я как раз выбрал первый вариант.

Comment: Ну я согласен что решение не элегантное, но зато простое и надёжное.

Comment: Чёто я подумал и всё таки согласен - перезагрузка перед носом бесит.

Comment: Может так случится, что на обеих вкладках будут изменения, тогда потеряете одну из них.

Answer (score 1):

есть 2 варианта автоматизации
1 использовать localStorage/sessionStorage+ листенер
2 использовать websocket, для отправки данных на неактивнуювкладку

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, для пользователя лучший вариант - синхронизация открытых вкладок через localStorage, см. [Storage Event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-event). Примечательно, что этот спсоб - [offline-first](http://offlinefirst.org/).

Comment: Я как раз использую событие onstorage для того чтобы назначить для других вкладок обработчик события windows.onfocus на перезагрузку. До этого пытался сделать обновление других вкладок в фоне по событию onstorage, но ни к чему хорошему это не привело: сложно, куча багов, даже тормоза в IE.

Comment: зачем делать презагрузку страницы? через localStorage можно передать что угодно и обновить вкладку без перезагрузки страицы.

Comment: но самое оптимальное использовать websocket. если нужно использовать старые браузеры - есть эмуляция на флэше. при использовании websocket обновлять страницы нет смысла, можно просто обновлять нужные данные. причем данные могут быть обновлены на вкладке даже в том случае если они были изменены другим пользователем, таким образом данные будут всегда актуальны. и если (к примеру) обновилась только одна ячейка в тамблице - нет смысла обновлять всю таблицу , достаточно обновить только эту ячейку.

Comment: Вадим, вы выбираете неправильный инструмент. Вебсокеты созданы для обеспечения быстрой передачи часто изменяемых данных (по несколько раз в секунду), где дорого постоянно производить переподключение и отправлять лишние данные. Лучше всего инструмент подходит под игровые, биржевые данные и, например, чат (и то с натяжкой). но не для форм.